# Need mm/dd/yyyy format in the first column of datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datatable

I'm reading values from excel and storing it in Datagridview. The first column of the datatable is Date and I need the format in mm/dd/yyyy, but it is showing mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM. I need only the date part.

I've tried using defaultcellstyle.Format and many other methods, but I've found no solution

```
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [POSFailures$]  WHERE Date =@param1", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("param1", todaydate));
        command.Connection = connection;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            sda.Fill(dtexcel2);
            connection.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return dtexcel2;
    }
```

I've tried using for loops and everything mentioned in google, but I'm still not getting the desired result. Any solution would be of great help!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the DataGridView after using the DefaultCellStyle.Format ? I also don't see this in your code anywhere. Does it still contain the time?

Comment: After the format property, I’m still not getting the desired format

Comment: I don't see your format code anywhere. Can you post the code where you are setting the format on the DataGridView?

Comment: And I’ve not added any columns in datagrid as I’m using the headers from excel

Comment: Post your code man, I don't see you setting DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy" anywhere! How do you expect it to format without you telling it the format you want? Post the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourDataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Comment: Tried even that. But no use

Comment: I’ve not added any columns in data grid as I’m using headers from excel to get column names

Comment: I'm getting syntax error[; expected] at "{colName}_OLD_COLUMN_NAME"; and invalid arguments at gridSource.Rows.Remove(oldColumn)

Comment: I've included the $ in front of the string, it still shows ; expected

Comment: But if the $ is removed, it works for the line. @DataColumn newColumn = gridSource.Columns.Add(colName); I'm getting this error - A column named 'Date' already belongs to this DataTable.

Comment: I'm getting only date in datagrid. But, I'm returning the dtexcel2(the datatable) back to datagridview which is its datasource. Again, i'm seeing date with time. Datatable has the mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM format

Comment: sorry i did not look at the end of your comment. I'm pleased to inform you that it worked finally. Thank you for helping me out. You made my day!